# Can chain-linked genetic segment data be used to reliably assign unknown relatives to either the donor's mother or father?

Tags: genetics, dna, molecular-genetics, human-genetics

I am analyzing DNA matching segment data, and I am trying to broadly group all DNA matches by my donor's parents.

Based on documented evidence, I can confidently identify "Person 'B'" as a familial match to my donor "Person 'A'" via a particular parent.

Is it probable that extrapolating the assignment of family members to each of the donor's parents by 2nd and 3rd step matching will yield accurate results?  I will explain my question more clearly below.

In my graphic below, persons 'A' and 'B' are known relatives via paper trail documentation.  "Person 'C'" shares common DNA segments with both 'A' and 'B', so I want to know if it is safe to accept "Person 'C'" as being related via the same parent as "Person 'B'" is to the donor without a supporting paper trail.

Furthermore, if it is indeed acceptable to identify person 'C' as being related via the donor's same parent, **would it be safe to also assume that "Person 'D'"**, who does not match "Person 'A'" (aka the donor) or 'B'(the paper-trail linked relative to the donor) *on the same segment* as "Person 'C'" but matches the donor and person 'C' each on unrelated segments, **is a genetic match via the donor's same parent?**

Here's a graphic to illustrate my scenario described:

[image]

If, in the illustration, person 'B' was known to be related to 'A' via the donor's father's side, is it highly probable that person 'D' would also be related via his father's side as opposed to his mother's side?

For the purpose of this question, **assume any direct descendants of the donor are excluded from the analysis**, only ancestors and branching descendants (parents, uncles, cousins etc.) are included .

Comment: Much depends on how unique your "matches" are. If they are short matches of low-polymorphism stretches of DNA, they are not worth much.  I'm a bit confused about what you mean by "related via ... side" in your examples. Posting one or more possible or putative family trees would help clarify things.

Comment: I'm finding that the answer is no. At least without considering polymorphisms. I did this across the donors father's matches, and the result is that about 84% of the donor's DNA would have come from his father. So that's definitely not right.